# Is there a way to get LibGit2Sharp to work on AlmaLinux 8 in an application built on Windows?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, libgit2, libgit2sharp

I have an ASP.NET Core application (.net core 2.1) built on Windows that uses LibGit2Sharp (version 0.26.2).

It works fine when running on Windows, but I have not been able to get it to work properly when running on an AlmaLinux 8 server.

I copied the libgit2-106a5f2.so file from the linux-x64 native runtime publish output to the same folder that contains LibGit2Sharp.dll on the AlmaLinux 8 machine.

This is the error I see:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'git2-106a5f2' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: libgit2-106a5f2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods.git_libgit2_init()
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods.InitializeNativeLibrary()
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods.git_repository_open_ext(git_repository*& repository, FilePath path, RepositoryOpenFlags flags, FilePath ceilingDirs)
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_repository_open_ext(String path, RepositoryOpenFlags flags, String ceilingDirs)
   at LibGit2Sharp.Repository.IsValid(String path)
...
```

**Edit**:

I set the LD_DEBUG and LD_LIBRARY_PATH variables, and got this output when it tried to load the libgit2 library:

```
   1413948:     file=libgit2-106a5f2 [0];  dynamically loaded by /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.1.30/libcoreclr.so [0]
   1413948:     find library=libgit2-106a5f2 [0]; searching
   1413948:      search path=/path/to/application/runtimes/linux-x64/native                (LD_LIBRARY_PATH)
   1413948:       trying file=/path/to/application/runtimes/linux-x64/native/libgit2-106a5f2
   1413948:      search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
   1413948:      search path=/lib64/tls:/lib64:/usr/lib64/tls:/usr/lib64                (system search path)
   1413948:       trying file=/lib64/tls/libgit2-106a5f2
   1413948:       trying file=/lib64/libgit2-106a5f2
   1413948:       trying file=/usr/lib64/tls/libgit2-106a5f2
   1413948:       trying file=/usr/lib64/libgit2-106a5f2
```

This file exists:

/path/to/application/runtimes/linux-x64/native/libgit2-106a5f2.so

But it appears that it is looking for the file without the ".so" extension?

Comment: Can [this](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/1703) help you?

Comment: not especially, it's not clear to me from the discussion what would need to happen to make this work

Comment: .NET Core 2.1 reached End Of Life years ago. Even .NET Core 3.1 is out of support now. The Long Term Support version is .NET 6.

Comment: Is the implication that if I re-write my application using .NET 6, this will automatically work?

Comment: The implication is that there's no guarantee your code will work for several years now, because maintainers stopped testing against .NET Core 2.1. In any case you aren't supposed to copy individual files when publishing but the entire `publish` folder. You can specify the target OS to generate a deployment just for it, eg Linux. In .NET 3 and later you can generate a single file executable

Comment: Besides, it's unclear what LibGitSharp2 version is used. The package uses `LibGitSharp2.NativeLibraries` to include native libraries. If you view the latest version [in the NuGet Package Explorer](https://nuget.info/packages/LibGit2Sharp.NativeBinaries/2.0.315) the included library is `libgit2-182d0d1.so`.

Comment: the entire publish folder is there...there is a runtimes folder that includes the various native libraries from LibGitSharp2.NativeLibraries.

it wasn't finding the library so I have done the manual copy in an attempt to put it somewhere that it can be found.

the libgit2sharp version being used is 0.26.2 (using LibGitSharp2.NativeLibraries version 2.0.306), which is the latest version that shows up in the VS nuget package manager

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251011/discussion-between-jceddy-and-panagiotis-kanavos).